# Save View Results in Table listener as a csv file in jmeter

Tags: csv, save, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running a test script on jmeter and I want to save the results I obtained from the 'View Results in Table' listener. I just don't understand how I would do this the same way I save the results in the Summary Report and Aggregate Report listener; that is, there is no 'Save Table Data' in the bottom of the View Results in Table unlike the other listeners. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

In 'View Results in Table' listener, there is Filename field.

1. Fill Filename field with correct local path
2. Click Configure button. Then configure as below picture
3. Run the test and check the result. The csv file will created.
   [image]

Comment: where will the csv file be created?

Comment: CSV file will be created at your local path that you have filled at Filename. i.e. Filename = D:\result.csv, Then the CSV file will be located in D:\

Comment: You can use set path to current directory like this `${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}result-table.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Summary Report and Aggregate Report have "Save Table Data" button because the majority of values in them are **calculated**.

View Results in Table listener just displays raw data therefore it does not require to calculate anything hence there is no "Save Table Data" button.

---

I am under impression that you are using JMeter a little bit wrong. Normally you should not be saving listeners output separately, moreover you don't even need the listeners during the test run.

1. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l results.jtl
   ```
2. After your test is done open JMeter GUI add a listener of your choice to Test Plan and open `results.jtl` file with that listener

Make sure that all the listeners are either disabled or deleted during the test execution as they cause huge memory overhead which may cause lesser throughput or even ruin your test. See [Greedy Listeners - Memory Leeches of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) arcticle for more detailed explanation.